# How to tell JavaScript that my variable is an array and not a string?

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask

I'm using flask and my backend returns to AJAX a response in the form of a python list, and then JavaScript understands it as a string, but that's a problem because I have to iterate over that list.

All i could find on the internet is how to check the type of a variable, but couldn't find any method (which in python is pretty straightforward) to change it

Comment: Try `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Array.isArray() to check for array..typeof keyword to know the type of variable

Comment: But the variable is a string @ShivendraGupta - so `Array.isArray` and `typeof` return `false` and `"string"` respectively.

Comment: Most of the times HTTP response are coming like a string. So you can do two things. First, you have to check it is that data are string type? if so convert them into an object. `typeof response === 'string'` then `JSON.parse( response )`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON string into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461142/parse-json-string-into-an-array)

Comment: @JackBashford i don't get it. should the flask route have the line: return JSON.parse(name_of_the_list) ? currenty it has return name_of_the_list

Comment: This link will help you. Array.isArray() https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_isarray

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing python list to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175519/passing-python-list-to-javascript)

Comment: Can you post a sample of the string you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

If your response is a string, you can use `JSON.parse` to turn it into an JS Object/Array.

```
var response = someAjaxStuff(...);
// response is a string
response = JSON.parse(response);
// now reponse is an Object/Array
```

If you use AJAX with jQuery, you can also use `dataType`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://example.com/api/somejson',
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'get',
    success: function(res) {
        // console.log res will be an object/array here.
    }

});
```

But if you're writing your own API, I suggest you have to add the right header to tell browser that it is a JSON format instead of string.

For flask you can use `jsonify` ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945523/forcing-application-json-mime-type-in-a-view-flask)):

```
return jsonify(somedict)
```

Comment: i'm trying the first option you presented, and i get the console error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 2"

Comment: Maybe your string is not a valid JSON. You can validate your string [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

Comment: my string is actually a python list [[a,b,c],[d,e,f],...]

Comment: If that's not a JSON, it's impossible for JS to read that string (unless you write a parser for that). Make sure your API can response a valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The `Array.isArray()` method determines whether the passed value is an Array or not.

```
var someNumbers = [1,2,3];
console.log( Array.isArray( someNumbers ) );
```

and if it is an array it will return

```
true
```

Check this link to know more about [Array.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

Comment: That's not the question that's being asked; OP *knows* that JavaScript is working with a string, but s/he wants to force his JavaScript to understand it's really an array.